# ng-bind-html not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

a.html

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlElement()"></div>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.htmlElement = function(){ 
  var html = '<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" />'; 
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

But when I want to get the value of the text input using

```
alert($scope.myModel);
```

It says myModel is undefined. It only happens when I add the text input dynamically.

How can I get the value of that text input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use this DOM manipulation with directive instead.

In your `controllers.js`:

```
app.directive("myHtml", function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" />',
       link: function(scope, attr){
           scope.myModel = 'Input text here';
       }
   } 
});

app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope) {  

    $scope.showInputText = function(){
        alert($scope.myModel);
    }
});
```

In your `HTML`:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-html><my-html>
    Your input: {{myModel}}
    <button ng-click="showInputText()">Show Input Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your solution also works. I wish I could vote up for your answer if my reputation is above 15...

Answer (score 0):

try this, http://plnkr.co/edit/A4HRCuTbJt21wEngH9HX?p=preview :

```
   <div ng-bind-html="htmlElement()" compile-element></div>
```

....

```
    module.directive("compileElement", function($compile){
      return {
        link: function(scope,element) {
          scope.$watch(function(){
            return element.html();
          }, function() {
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }); 
        }
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following css to your div / element

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```